# Tourist visa to China - return ticket

Tags: visas, china

I live in Europe. I will be flying to Shanghai and travelling south to Nanning for 1 month. Then I will leave to Vietnam by train. My flight back to Europe from Asia is 4 months later, so I don't have any ticket out of China - I'm flying back from Bangkok.

As far as I know I cannot get the visa without it. One solution I see would be to buy a plane ticket from Nanning to Hanoi, and specifying this in the visa application.

The problem is that it's very expensive. How can I be sure that after spending so much money I will get the visa in the end?

Is there an easier solution to this?

Comment: Do the application criteria specify that it has to be a plane ticket? Will your onward train ticket with confirmed date and seat to your destination in Vietnam suffice?

Comment: You could just get a fully refundable ticket, no? That is expensive but will incur you no losses when you cancel after obtaining the visa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

China immigration is really allergic to ground transportation tickets. Non-residents who apply for a Chinese visa in HK (with the intent of crossing on foot into Shenzhen) get denied a visa regularly. You need a flight in and out of China when applying for a visa. Which can be inconvenient...

The usual solution here is to apply for a visa via a travel agency: they make up an itinerary for you, and document it with real fake bookings, ie real bookings that will be cancelled after the visa is issued. Costs a little more, but it is hassle-free.

Comment: +1, but having flights is not absolutely required: I just got an Chinese visa for entering by train from Mongolia, and it was enough to show a flight to Russia shortly before the entry date and a flight out from Hong Kong.

Comment: Thanks! To stay on the safe side, I will buy a plane ticket (I would have to buy some ticket to Vietnam anyway). If I have a flight on 01.09 which arrives to Shanghai on 02.09, can I fly out on 01.10? (it's the 30th day).